# Use CSS classes in Vue based on breakpoints

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have tried using a vuetify class based on breakpoint it worked

`<v-app :class="{'yellow': !$vuetify.breakpoint.xs}">`

I have a class named pagemargin in a vue file
But when I use this class it is not working, as in the following case

`<v-app :class="{'pagemargin': !$vuetify.breakpoint.xs}">`

why is it not working?

```html
<style >
.pagemargin{
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Does the class append to the element and the styles not working?

Comment: yes style is not working

Comment: then you are sure that class is getting added to the element in the DOM?

Comment: yes it is getting added

Comment: yes, try adding the `!important` as mentioned in the answer, your styles might be getting overridden by some other ore defined styles

Comment: It is working right now ,

Answer (score 0):

Add `!important` to your styles. Vuetify adds its default style to the whole v-app so you need to override it.

```css
.pagemargin{
  margin-right: 100px !important;
  margin-left: 100px !important;
  color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help , I just deleted the file and tried it in a new file it is working with the previous code I wrote

Comment: Glad it worked. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Using `!important` might work, but in long term as your application gets bigger, it could be costly. You should instead, solve this by providing a CSS that has a higher specificity than that of Vuetify. I provide you with an example:

```
<template>
  <div class="my-div">
    <v-btn :class="{'my-padding': !$vuetify.breakpoint.xs}" tile outlined color="success">
      View
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
 /* this wont work */
.my-div .my-padding {
  padding-right: 200px;
  padding-left: 200px;
}

/* this works */
.my-div .v-btn.my-padding {
  padding-right: 200px;
  padding-left: 200px;
}
</style>

<style scoped>
/* this also works */
.my-div .my-padding {
  padding-right: 200px;
  padding-left: 200px;
}
</style>
```

You can read more about specificity [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).